# How to configure AptanaStudio 3 autocomplete

Tags: jquery, html, aptana

So I've been reading that Aptana is one of the better free IDEs for web development. I'm primarily looking for a good solid autocomplete engine for web (for tools such as jQuery).

I tried out Aptana 3, but it doesn't seem to do include jQuery in autocomplete even though I've included it in my index.html file.

Any suggestions? Should I try another editor?

I think what fiddlesalad does is ideal: http://fiddlesalad.com/javascript/
However it seems to be web only.

Comment: Have installed the jQuery bundle? accessible under Commands > Bundle Development > Install Bundle

Comment: I just did that. The commands I'm interested are in the pull down menu, but not in the autocomplete menu.

Comment: this approach works best for me  https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries

Comment: @AntarrByrd, I have been using this for a while now, but it seems it's not maintained (the latest available doc file is for jQ 1.6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands->Bundle Development->Install Bundle and then select jQuery from the list. 
Please select this as the best answer if you found it helpful.